# Unity: On mouse click onto box collider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a quick question, it seems pretty simple but I can't get my head around. I am trying to click on a door by mouse click which will then open. So basically an animation will play after mouse click, this is all working already in my project but unfortunately the door will open wherever I click but it should obviously only open when I click on the door. I made a box collider around the door and set it to trigger but it doesn't fix my problem.

Would anyone be able to help? I would really appreciate it.

Here is my current code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ScriptTor : MonoBehaviour
{
  private void Update()
  {
      if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
      {
          GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("Tor");
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to actually check whether the mouse position during your click is inside the collider, e.g.: by performing a raycast

Comment: thank you, I am just pretty new to unity and im not so sure how to do the raycast checking...

Comment: please use the correct tags ... [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long deprecated by now ... your code is clearly `c#`

Answer (score 2):

`Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)` does not check if you are currently clicking on your door, and is simply fired whenever you click when your game run (wherever on the window)

I suggest you to look at this thread [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/615771/how-to-check-if-click-mouse-on-object.html), which implies the use of Raycasts

Answer (score 2):

If you have a 3D scene, you propably need to use raycast:
Try

```
if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
    {
        // Check if hit.transform is door, 
        if(...) GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("Tor");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is still opening the door wherever I click, I am not so sure what I am doing wrong. There is a collider infant of the door and the tick is on trigger

Comment: I am not sure what I have to put into the last if statement?

Comment: if the name of the door is "door" you could use if (hit.transform.gameObject.name == "door")